# How do I tell Excel that this isn't a comma delimited list?

Tags: excel, csv

I have a list that I'd like to pull into Excel and work with, but Excel is treating it as CSV, which it isn't. The list looks something like this:

```
Last Name, First Name -- Title, Department
Last Name, First Name -- Title, Department, Other Department
Last Name, First Name -- Title, Department
Last Name, First Name -- Title, Department
Last Name, First Name -- Title, Department
```

What I want to do is split it on the `--`, then split the names on the comma and split the title from the list of departments probably with a compound formula that uses `=find` and `=left` to separate the titles out. That's all fine. I can do that. But for some reason just pasting the list to begin with is giving me grief. Excel 2011 sees the commas and gives me this:

```
Last Name | First Name -- Title | Department
Last Name | First Name -- Title | Department
Last Name | First Name -- Title | Department | Other Department
Last Name | First Name -- Title | Department
Last Name | First Name -- Title | Department
```

I don't get any dialog, it just does it. And I've simplified this -- some department names actually have commas in them, some people are in three or four departments. The net result is a big mess. I really just want to paste one line per cell and do it myself, but I can't find anything in Paste Special or anywhere else to tell Excel to lay off interpreting delimiters.

How do I make it stop?

Comment: Isn't there a little paste button after pasting in excel? If you click it, you should be able to get the text import wizard instead and if not, you will instead have the option to paste it as raw text.

Comment: type any text in a cell, select that cell, go to Data \ Text to Columns \ Delimited, uncheck the Comma box and Finish. When you paste, it won't split it anymore

Comment: @Jerry, that's it -- I didn't notice the paste button. If you add that as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I love it when I'm proven wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a little paste button after pasting in excel.

It looks a bit like that (image snatched on google xD):

[image]

If you click it, you should be able to get the text import wizard instead and if not, you will instead have the option to paste it as raw text.

Answer (score 1):

Let it 'do it's thing', insert a column after `First Name -- Title`, select `First Name -- Title` and Data > Data Tools > Text to Columns , select Delimited, Next, select Other: (only) and insert hyphen, check Treat consecutive delimiters as one, Finish.

Then similar process for `Last Name, First Name` column etc, with comma as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that after you do a text import with a delimiter, it will perform the same operation on the next set of data that matches those rules. Thus, if you have tried comma delimiting, it didn't provide you with the results you wanted, then pasted to try something else, you would get the same results.

Try exiting Excel and pasting in the text again.